# Host won't go to sleep while VMWare Workstation 16 Player is running

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Sometime this year after I updated to version 16, VMWare Player will no longer allow my host Windows 10 PC to go to sleep while the program is running. Is there a setting I can change to allow this? It is very annoying, and was not an issue for the past decade or so, but suddenly is now. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using VMware Workstation instead. I have 3 machines here. I close the lid, everything suspends. I open the lid and all is well - all the machines. Workstation will do this for you.

Comment: It might be that the upgrade to version 16 went badly, and a clean install will fix it. You might consider uninstalling VMWare, cleaning out its folders, reinstall and add the VMs.

Comment: I did a complete uninstall and reinstall. This removed the "Sleep" option completely from the Start menu *and* the control panel applet somehow! I had to use the command line to get it all back since the control panel applet wasn't working. Program seems to be working correctly now though.